# How to scrape all the text with scrapy get all methode with <br> in the node?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to get all the text using xpath but I can only get the first part each time.

```
body = comment.xpath("normalize-space(.//blockquote/text())").getall()
```

```html
<blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer ugc baseHtml">
                        
                        
12+5 I think I was? It was whichever day I had my twelve week scan, about a few hours before. He felt like a goldfish turning over in a bag of water. 
<br>
<br>
I am autistic and am naturally more sensitive to things going on in my body so it’s probably that.
<div class="messageTextEndMarker">&nbsp;</div>
</blockquote>
```

Could someone help me to get the whole text as a result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `//blockquote/normalize-space()` or `normalize-space(.//blockquote)`

Comment: I had this as an error : ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //blockquote/normalize-space()

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
body = comment.xpath('normalize-space(.//blockquote)').get()
```